# Use twips for resolution independent measurement?

Tags: printing, resolution, units-of-measurement

In Java, if I making a graphical editing component, should I use twips as the unit of measure or is the twip now obsolete in favor of some other unit?

I want to have a unit that can be used to deliver output to high resolution printers.

Answer (score 1):

You are basically asking for an opinion. Pixels, twips, millimeters, inches do their job and you will always need additional information (like a device's resolution) in order to convert coordinates, lengths and similar. It doesn't really matter if you use twips or, say, millimeters, but you have to be consistent. You should rather prepare for implementing/using the conversion between different measurement units than to stick with a specific one.

If you think of printing it out and applying a ruler on the sheet to measure if everything is correct, you wouldn't be better off dealing with twips - or do you have a twips-based ruler? ;) Also, in a conversation with someone else, who may not be familiar with twips, you would have a better communication basis using a measurement unit common for both. So personally, I prefer millimeters in such cases, but the same problems arise, when I talk to someone, who uses inches. You won't be able to make everyone happy.

Finally, it is on you to decide for a strategy. The only rule of thumb I can think of is: Use the most common thing in your domain. If you're doing everything on your own, do what you like. If someone helps you or you prepare something for someone else, you have to be able to talk to this "someone" in a way he/she understands without additional effort of conversion.

These are only some thoughts that came to my mind ad hoc; surely there are lots of further rationales depending on what exactly you are trying to do and what you are planning for the future of your code. Hope this helps.

Comment: I am specifically looking for applicability to high-end printers, so it is not a matter of opinion. Either high-end printers use twips or they don't. I want to follow whatever convention is currently typical for modern printers that are over 600 dpi.

Comment: OK, I see. How do you print? Which classes/methods do you use? A short boilerplate example of your code would be helpful. As far as I can see for now, Java doesn't seem to offer much support on printer information - at least I found nothing about measure units and some say not everything regarding printing in Java works as expected. Without getting supported measure units automatically you would have to create a large table with printers vs. supported measure units. I don't think this is what you want. Are you forced to use Java or could you do this in .NET as well?